# jQuery Change Background image gradually by scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not pretty good in java. Still I guess that question is not too easy for pros as well.

As the header says I'm trying to find a solution how to change a background image gradually by scroll with jQuery.

The background should be responsive.

I found a website having a similar thing [sojournnetwork.com](http://sojournnetwork.com/)

Since I'm no pro with java and jquery a jsfiddle example would be nice!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a perfect tutorial for your needs.

http://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/recreate-nikebetterworld-parallax/

This is the result of the tutorial:

http://ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/

Comment: Thanks a lot,... I gonna try it with this and will later put a link of it here.

Answer (score 0):

The background image dont change, just is Fixed.

```
div.background {
background-image:url(xxx);
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

And every "new" image is a container `div` who scroll like another.
Something like this must work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this effect is typically called "Parallax". You might find some of the following examples helpful:

- http://wagerfield.github.io/parallax/
- http://stolksdorf.github.io/Parallaxjs/

You can also search google for the word "Parallax" and find some simple scripts that don't require an external library if that is a requirement. I did find [this](http://jsfiddle.net/webdesigner/JBR2s/) JSFiddle which might be helpful as well. I believe it uses the following to setup the backgrounds:

```
background: url(http://www.webdesignermagazine.nl/files/2012/06/golf.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for, just I didn't know the name of that system. And your links helped me to find the answers for projected websites!